Home page goes to login if loaded from URL
Setup:
I installed React (Vite) and I developed a home page that should appear only if user is authenticated. If not, the page should go to the login page.
npm create vite@latest my-app --template react
npm install
npm install react-router-dom
npm run dev

The backend is Django and Reacts uses
user/api/user-auth-status

to know if the user is authenticated.
The header is also shown only to the authenticated user. The footer shown to everyone.

Problem
The problem is that if I login from the login page, the home page is shown fine. But if I go to home page / from the header or from the URL bar in my browser, I would be navigated to the login page again.
I am very new to React. I do not understand what is the problem and whether my state user is updated properly or not.

Codes
App.jsx
import './App.css';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProtectedRoute from './ProtectedRoute';
import PageNotFound from './PageNotFound';

function App() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUserStatus = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}user/api/user-auth-status`);
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Failed to fetch user status');
                }
                const data = await response.json();
                setUser(data.user);
            } catch (err) {
                setError(err.message);
                console.error('Error fetching user status:', err);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        fetchUserStatus();
    }, []);

    const handleLogin = (userData) => {
        setUser(userData);
    };

    if (loading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error}</div>;
    }

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="App">
                {user && user.is_authenticated && <Header user={user} />}
                <div className="body">
                    <Routes>
                        <Route
                            path="/login"
                            element={<Login onLogin={handleLogin} />}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/"
                            element={
                                <ProtectedRoute user={user}>
                                    <Home />
                                </ProtectedRoute>
                            }
                        />
                        <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
                    </Routes>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;



ProtectedRoute.jsx
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


function ProtectedRoute({ children, user }) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!user || !user.is_authenticated) {
            navigate('/login');
        }
    }, [user, navigate]);

    if (user && user.is_authenticated) {
        return <>{children}</>;
    }

    return null;
}

export default ProtectedRoute;



Login.jsx
import './Login.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const getCSRFToken = () => {
    const match = document.cookie.match(/csrftoken=([\w-]+)/);
    return match ? match[1] : '';
};

function Login({ onLogin }) {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const csrfToken = getCSRFToken();

        fetch(`${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}user/api/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken,
            },
            credentials: 'include',  // Send cookies with the request
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: username,
                password: password,
            }),
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            if (data.detail === 'Login successful!') {
                onLogin({ username, is_authenticated: true });
                navigate('/');
            } else {
                alert('Login failed: ' + data.detail);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert('Error: ' + error.message);
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className="login-container">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            {error && <div className="error-message">{error}</div>}
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="username"
                        value={username}
                        onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="login-button">
                    Login
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;


Header.jsx
import React from 'react';
import './Header.css';
import MenuButton from './MenuButton';


function UserBox({user}) {
    if(user && user.is_authenticated)
        return (<>
                user: { user.username }<br/>
                <a href="/logout"><button>Logout</button></a>
            </>);
    else
        return (<>
                  <a href="/login"><button>Login</button></a>
            </>);
}


function Header({user}) {
    const debug = import.meta.env.VITE_DEBUG === 'true';
    const headerLinks = [
        { href: '/', label: 'Home' },
        { href: '/about/', label: 'About' },
        { href: '/contact/', label: 'Contact' },
    ];
  return (
    <div className="App-header">
        <div className="header" style={{ backgroundColor: debug ? '#feffd3' : '#dfffe0' }}>
            {headerLinks.map((link, index) => (
                <MenuButton key={index} url={link.href} text={link.label} />
            ))}
            <div style={{ padding: '10px', margin: '10px', display: 'inline-block' }}>
                <UserBox user={user} />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;


MenuButton.jsx
import React from 'react';
import './MenuButton.css';



function MenuButton({url, text}) {
    return (
        <div className="header-button">
            <a href={url}>{text}</a>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MenuButton;


Django authentication:
class UserAuthStatusView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request):
        is_authenticated = False
        username = ''
        email = ''
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated:
             is_authenticated = request.user.is_authenticated
             username = request.user.username
             email = request.user.email
        return Response({
                'is_authenticated': is_authenticated,
                'username': username,
                'email': email,
            })

Django Authentication:
@csrf_protect
def api_user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        username = data.get('username')
        password = data.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return JsonResponse({'detail': 'Login successful!'}, status=200)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'detail': 'Invalid username or password.'}, status=200)

    return JsonResponse({'detail': 'Only POST method allowed for login.'}, status=405)

.

"But if I go to home page / from the header or from the URL bar in my browser, I would be navigated to the login page again." - The address bar part makes sense, but how does your header effect navigation changes to other app routes? Can you [edit] to share the Header component code? Also, in fetchUserStatus what is the value of data.user that you save into the user state?

@DrewReese, added the header too. Thanks

Ok, I guess we'd need to see this MenuButton component, and everything down to the actual links a user is clicking on. And what about the data.user value from your "api/user-auth-status" endpoint?

@DrewReese, I added MenuButton.jsx. But regarding the API, you are right. It seems the cookies are not stored well. The result of the second call to http://localhost:8000/user/api/user-auth-status is {"is_authenticated":false,"username":"","email":""}.

I see. Yeah, if that effect in App is setting the user state to { is_authenticated: false, username: "", email: "" } then that's certainly going to navigate the user back to "/login" after a page reload. You'll need to inspect your backend code/logic to see why it returns this value instead of the expected user object. The header should probably also render React-Router-DOM Link components instead of raw anchor tags so the page isn't reloaded.

@DrewReese, after changing <a ... /> links to <Link to={url}>{text}</Link>, this problem did not occur anymore. But, I still do not understand why does django return user is unauthenticated even when the session id is sent correctly after I added credentials: 'include' to fetch for ${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}user/api/user-auth-status? I added the Django authentication too.

I have absolutely ZERO Django experience, but based on that code it would seem that request.user and request.user.is_authenticated is evaluating false and not changing any of the variable values you are returning in the JSON response.

@DrewReese, my problem was that I had to change setUser(data.user); to setUser(data);. totally different from what I was thinking. Thanks mate so much.

After page refresh, The state is lost in react, Make sure you are storing the token to verify  the login status when the page loads, Accordingly redirect the user, Also in your case try to add fetchUserStatus in dependency array and define this function outside the useEffect hook and wrap that in useCallback hook, then you call fetchUserStatus() in useEffect.
